# Adjust thickness of border surrounding legend key in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am drawing a map of new zealand with different regions colored differently. Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

nz <- map_data("nz")

value  <- data.frame(region = unique(nz$region), 
                     y = as.factor(1:length(unique(nz$region))))

nz <- nz %>%
        left_join(value, by = c("region"))

pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(22, "RdYlBu"))(22)

nzplot <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = y), data = nz) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal,
                    guide = guide_legend(direction = "vertical",
                                         override.aes = list(colour = "darkgreen"), 
                                         ncol = 3))
  ggsave("nzplot.pdf", nzplot, 
       width = 89, height = 80, units = "mm")
```

This creates the following figure:
[image]

Each legend key is bordered by a dark green frame thanks to `override.aes = list(colour = "darkgreen")`, but how could I adjust the thickness of this green border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thickness of the border could be adjusted via `size`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, fill = factor(am))) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 7) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "darkgreen", size = 5)))
```

[image]